# Struggling to display "element by id text" on top of "element by id image"

Tags: javascript, display

I am a novice programmer who is randomly shuffling an array of words and an array of images. In response to a button click, the program displays the "next word" with the "next image." I can currently display the word above the image, but I run into problems whenever I try to display the word anywhere on top of the image (preferably centered a marginal amount down from the top).

My Java code and HTML code include the following:

```
function drawcards(){  

var selected_word = document.getElementById("selected_word");  
var selected_image = document.getElementById("selected_image");  

selected_word.innerHTML = words[wkp_counter];  
selected_image.innerHTML = images[ikp_counter];  

}  

<div class="btn-group">  
<button onclick="shufflecards()">RESET</button>  
<button onclick="drawcards()">SELECT CARDS</button>  
</div>  
<p>  
<div id="selected_word"></div>  
<div id="selected_image"></div>
```

This works as expected, but does not deliver the desired result of displaying the word on top of the image. It seems like the solutions to somewhat comparable problems do not apply or work for this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to solve it with the Bootstrap framework. Just adding `class="text-center"` attribute in the last two divs in your HTML.

```js
let words = ['image 1','image 2','image 3'];
let images = ['https://picsum.photos/100','https://picsum.photos/200','https://picsum.photos/300'];
let wkp_counter = 0;
let ikp_counter = 0;
let selected_word = document.getElementById("selected_word"); let selected_image = document.getElementById("selected_image");  

function drawcards(){  
  selected_word.innerHTML = words[wkp_counter];  
  selected_image.innerHTML = '<img src="'+images[ikp_counter]+'">';  
}  

function shufflecards() {
  selected_word.innerHTML = '';  
  selected_image.innerHTML = '';  
  wkp_counter = getRandomInt(0, words.length - 1);
  ikp_counter = getRandomInt(0, images.length - 1);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group">  
  <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="shufflecards()">RESET</button>  
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="drawcards()">SELECT CARDS</button>  
</div>

<div id="selected_word" class="text-center"></div>  
<div id="selected_image" class="text-center"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Jordy, for responding to my question. When I run the code you provided, the name of the image appears ABOVE the image, and nothing appears on top of the image. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does the "top of image" sign mean that the word is located inside the image area but at the top end?